# Downgrade chromedriver version during runtime using webdrivermanager

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, webdrivermanager-java

**Problem:**

Facing an issue to downgrade chrome driver version during runtime.

**Background:**

Using chrome + Docan(needs chrome driver with v2.33) to do automation test of an application.

First, start chrome with driver version: 91.0.4472.124.
Then, switch to Docan which needs chrome driver with version 2.33.

**Code:**

```
WebDriverManager webDriverManager = null;
Initial: 
webDriverManager = WebDriverManager.chromedriver();
Switch:
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().clearResolutionCache();
webDriverManager = WebDriverManager.chromedriver().driverVersion("2.33");
webdriver.avoidBrowserDetection();
```

**Behavior:**

After switch:

System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver") --> return path for version 2.33

In log:

I could see chromedriver version is still 91

UI action:

Docan is not fully supported for actions like click.(It supports fine if driver is 2.33, tried with IE + Docan)

**Is there any suggestion to make it work?**

Comment: Chromedriver 2.33 only supports up to Chrome 62 though https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt One or two version late is usually workable, but v62 is released in 2017, Chrome already change too much. And what is this "docan"?

Comment: Hi Martheen, Docan is a secure browser gateway. Please check its official site here: https://www.connectone.co.jp/indexen.html

Comment: So this is a paid corporate product? Send an email to badger them so they upgrade their ancient app for compatibility with recent Chrome version, CC your CTO and security team for audit, and email for permission to deploy old Chrome/Chromium https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium. You'll want everything written in email so if one of them pester you "why it haven't been done" you can point out why, and if they force you to use old Chrome and inevitably something broke or leak data all over the place, you can point out you're forced to by your superior.